# Subsetting by factors in R loop

Tags: r, loops, split, subset

I am having difficulty subsetting my data by factors in a for loop. Here is a illustrative example:

```
x<-rnorm(n=40, m=0, sd=1)
y<-rep(1:5, 8)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
df_split<-split(df, df$y)
mean_vect<-rep(-99, 5)

for (i in c(1:5)) {
current_df<-df_split$i
mean_vect[i]<-mean(current_df)
}
```

`

This approach is not working because I think R is looking for a split called "i" when I really want it to pull out the ith split! I have also tried the subset function with little joy. I always run into these problems when I am trying to split on a non-numeric factor so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get split number `i` run

```
df_split[[i]]
```

BTW, as your final aim is `mean_vect` you better to use

```
mean_vect <- lapply(df_split, mean)
```

or:

```
mean_vect <- tapply(df$x, df$y, mean)
mean_vect
        1          2          3          4          5 
0.2566810 -0.1528079 -0.2097333 -0.1540343  0.3609312
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI, the functionality to accomplish this is typically done using `tapply`

```
tapply( df$x, df$y, mean )
```

The first argument specifies the value you want to "mean-group". The second is just the INDEX, i.e. the variable that splits your groups and the last is obviously the function you want to run on these groups, in this case mean.

Comment: ran2, the example, as it was written, matched Ruth's question data and didn't need a further example.  I left your clarification sentence.